# Removed middleware still being used

Tags: node.js, express

There are 2 middlewares I have configured on my app:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use("/assets",  express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

I was trying to get something to work and I added the following:

```
app.use("/public",  express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

but I ran into more trouble and decided to remove it, however the app still seems to be using it. 
Before I added it I had a products.ejs page that worked properly, but now all the links are broken and in the console inspector I get 2 errors:

1- `Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

2-`http://localhost:3000/products/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js`

My assets folder is in my root directory so it seems in the second error that the old middleware is still adding products to the route even though I deleted it.

Also if I rename the ejs and change the route from /products to /product and the render as well everything works.

Comment: There's no evidence that it's true. If you use middleware, you use it. If you don't, you don't. It could be a response from 404. The question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You're the only person who can check what server responses really are and make conclusions from that.

Comment: it seems to be this, if I create a duplicate route with the same ejs file and any other name it works well.